# Codeigniter ion auth trying to get the user name of a logged in user in to a string

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi team i am new to CI and ion auth and i want to find the best way to get the user name on the logged user and make it a string. I have try this and im getting an error.

Object of class CI_Email could not be converted to string

This is my Controller

```
 class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user();
        $email = $user->email;  

        $data['email']= $email;
        $data['mainContent'] = 'dashboard_view';
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

and view

```
<div id='dashboarWap'>
    <?php echo form_open('dashboard/dashInput'); ?> 

    <?php echo $email; ?>
```

Any idea on why i am getting this error would be a big help thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$this->ion_auth->user()` is a DB object.

`$this->ion_auth->user()->row();` returns the user object which you can query for first_name, number_of_cats_owned, or whatever.

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/controllers/auth.php

Comment: yeah worked that out just before you posted lol thanks for the help still

Comment: Number of cats owned is a good idea. I'm going to start storing that in my database LOL.

Answer (score 14):

Ion Auth sets the username, email, user id, and last login time in session variables when the user logs in (have a look at ln 683 ish in the **[ion_auth_model's](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/ion_auth_model.php)** login function.)

The simplest way to get this info is by using **[CI's session class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)** like so:

```
$username = $this->session->userdata( 'username' );
```

Of course, I abuse helpers so to make this even simpler I'll normally use a variant of this **[helper function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)**:

```
function userdata( $key, $val = null ){
  $ci = &get_instance();
  if ( $val !== null ){
    $ci->session->set_userdata( $key, $val );
  } else {
    return $ci->session->userdata( $key );
  }
}
```

This gives us a handy (& global scoped) function to call on as needed, wherever needed:

```
$username = userdata( 'username' );
```

Comment: NB on the helper function, remember to wrap it in an exists check. Also note, the overloading to involve `set_userdata` isn't the best as you now can't set a variable to `null` - its a trade off that rarely affects me so I go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ion auth already passes any data on logged in user through

```
$this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
```

You can access user name by doing this

```
foreach ($users as $value) {
    echo $value->first_name. " " . $value->last_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For get array data:

```
$this->ion_auth->user()->row_array();
```

For get object data:

```
$this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

as simple as:

```
$this->ion_auth->user()->row()->username;
```